# multifile upload doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom, file-upload, struts2

I have to send to an action (Struts2) some files for uppload from jsp.
This runs well.

```
<form action="uploads" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="upload" > 
    <input type="file" name="upload" > 
    <input type="file" name="upload" > 
    <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

but I need to perform some manipulation before send, so I have to send via javascript:

```
var form = document.forms.namedItem("loadform");  
form.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
form.method = "post";
var url = "./uploads";
form.action = url;
form.submit();
```

where

```
    <form id="loadform" name="loadform" action="uploads" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="attachs-<s:property value="#row.count"/>" style="width: 380px; position: relative; float: right; height: auto;"></div>
    </form>
```

and the DIV is populated using dom (I omit some step to reach the js function)):

```
function addInputFile(dad, baseid, idx, ww) {
    var elem = null;
    elem = document.createElement("input");
    elem.setAttribute("type",   "file");
    elem.setAttribute("id", baseid+"FX-"+idx);
    elem.setAttribute("name", "upload");
    elem.style.width = ww+"px";
    elem.style.fontSize = "11px";

    dad.appendChild(elem);
}
```

but this doesn't work!

the action does not see the List of files:
this is the code...

```
public String pdfUploads() {

    try {
        String targetPath = getText("pdf.repository");
        logger.info("###        Target Path: " + targetPath);

       for (File u : uploads) {
            logger.info("source *** " + u + "\t" + u.length());
        }
       for (String n : uploadFileNames) {
           logger.info(" dest. *** " + n);
       }
       logger.info(" end params *** ");
       File fileToCreate = null;
       for (int i=0; i<uploads.size(); i++) {
           File u = uploads.get(i);
           String n = uploadFileNames.get(i);
           fileToCreate = new File(targetPath, n);
           FileUtils.copyFile(u, fileToCreate);
              etc.
```

...and this is the log (logger in the for-loops are not considered):

```
24/07 10:07:33| INFO [http-apr-10080-exec-6] (PratModAction.java:591) - ###        Target Path: E:\JAVA\DLQ\pdfrepository
24/07 10:07:33| INFO [http-apr-10080-exec-6] (PratModAction.java:600) -  end params ***
```

and, obviously, the files are not loaded in the folder!
Why?

PS - the action is always the same that retrieves files sent by html form!

Comment: What is this `#row.count`?

Comment: is the way to distinguish several div (and forms) combined to several rows created using a struts2 iterator

Comment: ...but it does not seem to disturb or at least do not using the form in pure html

Comment: ..and this is another clue that convinces me the problem is in the javascript code...

Comment: although i've almost zero knowledge about java and struts2, i've to say that your html and javascript seems "ungood". use `<input type="file"  name="upload[]" multiple="true">` instead of repeating `<input type="file"  name="upload">` three times. 

then use FormData object to submit your form. It's much more better practice.  i can provide more code if you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: @m.mann do you have errors in the console?

Comment: Thanx marmeladse!  The ancient romans said "primum vivere deinde philosophari".  it could even be more elegant to use an array instead of repeating three times, but that's not the problem. I used  [input type="file"]  three times in the example html (that works). In reality I do not know how many times I have to use it and so I create it n times (according to the needs of the moment) using the DOM.
The real problem is in this way the files do not reach the action!
Maybe using a submit via JS I have to explicitate the list as a parameter in the url (url = "./uploads&uploads="+theList;?

Comment: Anyway thanx, I appreciate the suggestion and now I'll try to use a FormData object

Comment: no, Roman, no errors! just the two lines that I quoted above

Comment: It was just like that: I said it just to say something, and instead what was missing was to put the list into the url!.
I was convinced that invoking the form by its name was sufficient to recover all the elements inside but, evidently, it's not: you must specifically state everything!

Comment: I ask confirmation to some JS expert: is this true? if so, why then you must retrieve the name of the form to make the submit? It is superfluous!

Comment: Not at all!
I counted my chickens before they've hatched! It worked just because I had forgotten, between one test and another, removing the submit button!
In summary, the same form, even if created dynamically using DOM, if it sends the data to the action with the classic submit button works, with the JS script do not!

Comment: marmeladze I apologize! I didn't fully understand your suggestion! I get it now! But I can not use your method because I may not upload all the files at once: I have to give the user the ability to change the name before saving!

Comment: and moreover the user must also have the ability to upload  files from different folders